# C# - Store a decimal in file and read back

Tags: c#, decimal

Is it possible to store a decimal value in JSON format (string,object) within a text file  and subsequently retrieve it as a decimal without having to do any type casting / parsing etc?

For example the file may also have doubles stored within, these should not be parsed as decimals.

The file would contain no additional information to determine the variable type:

"num1": 4,

"num2": 5.4, (as double)

"num3": 563.2334 (as decimal)

Comment: why would you want to avoid parsing the values?

Comment: *"without having to do any type casting / parsing"* - how do you suppose to distinguish decimals from doubles in this case, if no parsing is allowed?

Comment: What sort of file is this? Text? Binary? JSON? XML? Does the reading code know which values should be decimal and which should be double? At the moment this question is very unclear.

Comment: file is a very vague term, I presume you mean a *text* file, in which case they only accept *text*..

Comment: Oh so now it's Json and not binary?

Comment: I don't even know what I m answering now....

Answer (score 6):

Yes it is possible through binary writer:

```
using(var bw = new BinaryWriter(File.OpenWrite("myFile.txt")))
{
    bw.Write(1234.01m); //there is actualy 16 bytes written to file. Double is 8 bytes long.
    bw.Write((double)5);
}
```

This way you will be able to avoid parsing its textual represenatation and load right into memory:

```
using(var br = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead("myFile.txt")))
{
    var myDecimal = br.ReadDecimal();//1234.01
    var myDouble = br.ReadDouble();//5
}
```

You don't need any additional data. Decimal and Double have different size in memory:

- Decimal is **16 bytes**
- Double is **8 bytes**

So if you want to store your values in JSON so bad to be able to extract it fast -> don't do this. It is probably not worth it, and this is why:

JSON is parsable format itself, and it **will** parse/convert it even if you store it inside byte array. If you prefer speed over readability - use other serialization frameworks. For example, **[protobuf](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net)**.

Comment: It's probably better *not* to give the file a .txt extension when it's explicitly not a text file.

Comment: Actualy, you can give any desirable extension and no extension at all. Just for test purposes so OP can see what is actually inside file.

Comment: Of course you can. You can call it "ThisFileContainsNoNumbers.txt". It will just be deliberately misleading.

Comment: And you don't need to give a file a .txt extension to be able to open it to test.

Comment: As I said, he can ensure himself, what there is no "parsable" data is stored. That is why I chose to make it txt.